# New Outlook Email Item Shortcut

Tags: mac, ms-office

I am looking for a way to create a keyboard shortcut or an icon I can click on that will simply open a blank Outlook email.

I found several solutions for Windows but I need to do this for my Mac. I've been trying a few options but none can just open a new Outlook email with one click or one keystroke.

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific as to where you want this icon/shortcut? From Outlook? From the Finder? From everywhere?

Answer (score 1):

**Use an email template**

1. Open Outlook
2. Create a new message (<kbd>⌘ Command</kbd><kbd>N</kbd>)
3. Immediately "Save as Template" to the Desktop (File -> Save As Template)
4. Shortcut will be created on your Desktop with the name `<no subject.emltpl>` rename it if you like.

Just double-click that template file every time you want to open a new email.